# Identify if the download pdf list item is getting tracked using OLD GA tag or via GTM tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Please advise on the below link, if the download list item is getting tracked via OLD GA tag or is it via GTM tag? When i inspect the element i cant find the hardcoded GA tag if it was tagged via old GA tag, however an event is being registered in the Google TAG assistant. Please advise.

https://www.capgemini.com/investor/capgemini-binding-corporate-rules

Regards,
Srijith

Answer (score 0):

In your website you have two Google Tag Managers.

Whenever you clicking to download PDF button, GTM is sending event (for example `category:Download;action:PDF;label:Capgemini Binding Corporate Rules`) to two different Google Analytics accounts:

- UA-49360690-10
- UA-49355528-1